# How to limit the products on homepage magento also show all properties?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am using magento rwd theme.

I want to limit the number of products to be shown to 4.
Also I want to show all the things like add to cart button, reviews section and price.

Currently I tried and tested the following code but it's not working.

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="19"  mode="grid" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" column_count="4" limit="4" }}
```

How can it be done?

I am attaching a screenshot of the output I am getting.
[image: Output screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not set the 'limit' for `catalog/product_list`  block in such a way.

The best place (please correct me if there is a better place/event) is via the event 'core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before'.

This will allow you to instantiate the toolbar and change the limit.

The code is easy and straightforward.
Your observer file,

```
class Test_Module_Controller_Router
{
public function homeProductCollection($observer)
    {
        try{
            $block=$observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
            if($block instanceof Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List){
                if($block->getProductLimit()){
                    $toolbar=$block->getToolbarBlock();
                    $block->setToolbarBlockName($toolbar->getNameInLayout());
                    $toolbar->setData('_current_limit',$block->getProductLimit());
                }   
            }
        }catch (Exception $e){
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Your xml file,

```
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        ...
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                <observers>
                    <test_module>
                        <class>Test_Module_Controller_Router</class>
                        <method>homeProductCollection</method>
                    </test_module>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        </events>
        ...
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

The CMS block used to create this would look like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" product_limit="2" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

For more information check [here](http://www.proxiblue.com.au/blog/smarter-cms-category-product-limits/)

Comment: Sorry , I am not an complete magento guy (I am newbie to magento) .So the steps you said above are just out of my mind. Can you please explain me that are you telling me to create a new extension? (If yes then can you provide me the steps) . Thanks

Comment: Steps are already there in the link given. and for observer check here http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/magento-event-observers-for-customer-registration-success/

Comment: Create simple module with `config.xml` and a model class. you can search in google for that. Will update with complete module soon, but you need to try before that

Comment: Still confused.
Is there no easier way to do this?

Comment: Will try and respond in next 24 hours

Comment: There are other solutions but not proper & feasible

Comment: Hi, I tried the above code as given by you but I am getting an error which is not allowing me to open even admin panel. please check the attached link https://gist.github.com/bhargavmehta/88e1921f419a1fcc784a